How does the introducing antiparticles justify the Klein-Gordon equation being second order in time?
The Klein-Gordon equation
$$(\square + m^2)\varphi = 0$$
is second order in time, and thus to obtain a unique solution we must supply two initial conditions. Viewing $\varphi$ as a wave function, this means we must supply an initial wavefunction $\varphi_0$ and its time derivative. If we view $\varphi$ as a field then we must supply the initial field configuration as well as its initial momentum. As far as I understand, this was one of the initial problems with the Klein-Gordon equation and what motivated Dirac to look for a first order equation.
I have read that one way around this problem is to split the positive and negative energy solutions so we can view the Klein-Gordon equation as a system of first-order equations, with the interpretation that the first equation in the system describes particles and the second antiparticles. Thus we must only supply as an initial condition a vector containing the initial state of the positive energy solution and the initial state for negative energy solution and no initial momenta is necessary.
However from the theory of differential equations, wouldn't the first equation in this system be an equation for $\varphi$ and the second for $\partial_t \varphi$? And so it seems we are calling $\partial_t \varphi$ the antiparticle/negative energy solution which doesn't seem right.
How does taking the point of view of particles/antiparticles get around the issue of the Klein-Gordon equation being second order in time and having to supply initial momentum?

I think you are seriously misunderstanding what is happening. We are not saying that there is a legitimate interpretation of KG nor Dirac equations in QM. We are saying that both of them are only well-interpreted as QFT equations, because in QFT you have the natural separation of particle and anti-particle parts of the spectrum, and both of them can be recast in a form that the energies are positive. In particular, the system of equations is not one for $\varphi$ and another for $\partial_t\varphi$, but rather a pair that respects the natural separation between particle and anti-particle.

@naturallyInconsistent Thank you for your comment. I think I may have poorly worded my question, but my intention was to ask it for both QM and QFT. What I mean is in QFT the equation is still second order in time and so it would require an initial momentum for the field, and supplying initial momentum is usually not desirable in physics. I assume this is not necessary because, as you mentioned, the field can be recast as a system of first order equations (one for the particles and the other for antiparticles)?

Yes, the information that is originally in $\varphi$ and $\partial_t\varphi$ has to be recast as particle and anti-particle, and then after the QFT re-interpretation, the wrong behaviour goes away.

@naturallyInconsistent As Maxwell's equations satisfy the KG prescription (for $m=0$) individually for $\Psi = \vec E$ and $\Psi = \vec B$, where goes the probabilistic behavior of $\vec E, \vec B$ which are kinds of like a $\Psi$ wave?
